# HP V1910 - Why is tagged traffic going to VLAN1?

Tags: switch, vlan, trunk

HP(3Com) V1910 switch with 2 vlans: VLAN1 (native) and VLAN191

The Trunk Port is configured like this:

[image]

Why are frames tagged for '191' also being forwarded to VLAN1?

Any ideas.

Thanks

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide your own answer and accept it.

Answer (score 4):

That port is set up to be a trunk. A trunk will carry both untagged (native) and tagged frames. You will forward both VLAN 1 (untagged) and VLAN 191 (tagged) frames on that port. If you want only VLAN 1 frames on the port, you need to set it to be an access port with only VLAN 1, or remove VLAN 191 membership from the trunk, instead of a trunk with both VLANs.